# AngularJS: set validity do not work when company with updating model in the same function

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS and I am trying to make a reset button for my form.
My model is a 2 dimensional array with validity for each cell.
I have to manually set values to null and reset the validity for each cell.

my code:

```
$scope.clear = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.nums.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.nums.length; j++) {
            $scope.nums[i][j] = null;
        }
    }
    angular.forEach($scope.myForm.$$controls, function (v, k) {
        v.$setValidity('', true);
    });
};
```

and the button:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="clear();" value="Clear" />
```

the problem is after the button is clicked, only the values are cleared and not the validity, but when I click it again (when all the values are cleared), the validity is cleared.

How can I get both of these to happen by clicking the button only once?

Answer (score 1):

In order to reset the form to its original state you can use in your code the [`$setPristine`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine) function which:

> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state
>   to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class.
>   Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
>
> This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this
>   form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want
>   to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

Your **code** would go like this: `$scope.myForm.$setPristine()`.

You might also want to take a look at [`$setUntouched`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setUntouched)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I know `$setPristine()` and  `$setUntouched` but they do not help because these functions just reset the class of the form itself, not of the controls (in my case). Maybe because I set the validity to exactly each control in the form, not only the form.
However, I solved it by myself already, I just have to add the validation error key string for the function and everything work well :D. Thanks again.